# Numbering a column of mixed items

Tags: excel

I have a column with multiple labels that I need to number. eg:

```
A|1
B|1
C|1
A|2
B|2
B|3
C|2
A|3
A|4
```

So each A gets listed 1 through 4 even though there are Bs and Cs in between.  The Bs and Cs also need to get numbered.

Comment: What is unclear here? Please vote to reopen. @rene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first letter is in A2, place this formula in B2 and copy down to the last letter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

What this does is place the count of all the prior occurrences of the letter on the current row (including the current row) in the cell.

Comment: This is beautiful, can't think of prettier alternative solution (banging my head on the screen for past 5 full minutes...).